# FabricJs Loaded Image From URL Doesn't Stretch To Fit Image Object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In the image below there is a canvas of 1000x1000, there is a rectangle object with the grey backgroundd of 900x300 at position 50,50 and a border black. Inside the rectangle is a fabric image object which is just loading In a square image of a pug.

The image object is the same size as the rectangle 900x300 positioned at 50,50 on the canvas (same as the rectangle).You can see the highlighted image object bounding box is the same size as the rectangle, how it should be, but the image itself isn't stretching to fill the size of the image object. What I want to see is the pug being the 900 width of the image object and the height based on the actual JPG ratio; so if the image itself is 300x300 and the width is 900 then the height of the image should also be 900 but obviously the bottom would be hidden because the object is only 300 high.

Does anyone know how I can make the JPG stretch to fit the image object?

[image]

```
    var img02URL = 'http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg';   
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mainc');

        var clipRect1 = new fabric.Rect({
            originX:'left',
            originY:'top',
            left:50,
            top:50,
            width:900,
            height:300,
            fill:'#DDD',
            stroke:'black',
            strokeWidth:2,
            selectable:false
        });
        clipRect1.set({
            clipFor:'test1'
        });
        canvas.add(clipRect1);

    var image1 = new Image();
        image1.onload = function(img){
            var image = new fabric.Image(image1,{
                width:900,
                height:300,
                left:50,
                top:50,
                clipName:'test1',
                clipTo:function(ctx){
                    return _.bind(clipByName,image)(ctx);
                }
            });
            canvas.add(image);
        }
        image1.src = img02URL;

var clipByName = function (ctx) {
        this.setCoords();

        var clipRect = findByClipName(this.clipName);

        var scaleXTo1 = (1 / this.scaleX);
        var scaleYTo1 = (1 / this.scaleY);
        ctx.save();

        var ctxLeft = -( this.width / 2 ) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
        var ctxTop = -( this.height / 2 ) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
        var ctxWidth = clipRect.width - clipRect.strokeWidth + 1;
        var ctxHeight = clipRect.height - clipRect.strokeWidth + 1;

        ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );

        ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
        ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.rect(
            clipRect.left - this.oCoords.tl.x,
            clipRect.top - this.oCoords.tl.y,
            ctxWidth,
            ctxHeight
        );
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    function findByClipName(name) {
        return _(canvas.getObjects()).where({
                clipFor: name
            }).first()
    }
```

Comment: use scaleX and scaleY for image to stretch to width and height respectively.

Comment: that also scales the image object itself though so the bounding box is still bigger than the image

Comment: how you are loading the image inside rectangle?? can you make a snippet/jsfiddle?

Comment: added some code, sorry it's only test code so a bit messy. If I put scaleX and scaleY on the image element it does indeed scale the JPG but it also makes the object itself scale up - leaving the same issue.